# Can my spouse sponsor me for a UK visa if I am unemployed?

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

I am a 28 years old Nigerian, who was schooled in the UK but now lives in Nigeria. I have traveled to the US, Middle east and the UK separately in the past 2 years when I had a job. I have now left my job because of marriage and have relocated to another city with my spouse. I want to apply for a tourist visa to the UK; my husband will be sponsoring me but won't be making the trip with me.

However, if I say that I am unemployed will this affect my application?

Comment: I see no way you can *not* say you're unemployed without lying.

Comment: @user92844 If you say you’re employed, how will you prove it? I suspect you already know the answer to your question - it is likely that being unemployed will be a negative. If you have very strong ties otherwise (husband, young children, for example) you might stand a chance but if I were you I wouldn’t risk a refusal on my otherwise exemplary travel history just for a holiday, I’d wait until I had a job again. If

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think the charitable reading would be that the OP is asking if being unemployed is too much of a factor to overcome in their visa application; rather than suggesting they'll lie.

Answer (score 12):

**This is a perfectly normal situation.** Plenty of people stop working when the get married, and are supported by their spouse. Plenty of people have trips abroad paid for by their spouses. Being in that situation does not invalidate you from getting a visa.

(In UK visa applications the word 'sponsorship' is not usually used in this situation. It's usually used only for when someone from the UK invites a person to go there, or in other situations related to work or student visas.)

When you fill in the application form it asks you who is paying for this trip, and how much. Put your husband's name in there. You will need to supply proof of your husband's financial status, to prove that he can afford it and that the trip is a reasonable thing to do, as well as your own finances. When you are asked about ties to your own country you will need to list the ties that tie your husband to the country too, such as his job, house you own or rent, property he owns etc. Be sure to state that your husband will not be accompanying you - that is an additional tie to your home country.

Nobody can tell you the chances of your getting the visa, but you probably have as much chance as a single person in the same employment and financial situation as your husband.

And absolutely tell the truth. Lying on your application to make it look better is very likely to result in a refusal and a ban from entering the UK.